# Efficient implementation of filter with impulse response $h_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: filters

I am studying computer science and come across the need to efficiently implement the filter with impulse response $h_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (n > 0)$. In general, $h_n = \frac{1}{q(n)}$ with any nonexponential and sublinear $q(n)$ such as $q(n)=\ln x$ is fine.

Cutting off  $h_n$ using some window is a possible solution. However, I am looking for exact methods or other approximate methods (like approximating the z transfer functions). Efficient implementations are the ones which have fixed space complexity and linear time complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not well behaved for n <= 0

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. I means $h_n$ is defined for $n>0$. I edited accordingly.